# "Please select Android SDK" - how to import project files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a new user to Android Studio. I have a zip packed from Udacity that I am trying to open/run in Android Studio.  The package is here - [Starter Code Zip File](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/April/58e82999_firebase-analytics-green-thumb-android/firebase-analytics-green-thumb-android.zip).

I have no instructions as to how to get this into Android Studio.  Left to my own devices, I am currently stuck at a place where, if I try to run the app, I get an error saying **"Please select Android SDK**.

I have checked everywhere for a solution to this, and the only two things I've found were:

1. Making sure the path to my Android SDK folder is correct within Android Studio settings (it is)
2. Making sure the same path is matched in the project **local.properties** file (it is)

The fact that these are both set properly (I think) leads me to believe that I just did the whole import wrong and should start from scratch.  But I don't really know what to do with that zip file to get it (properly) into Android Studio.

Initially I just went to **File > Open** and then selected the project **build.gradle** file from the zip package.  Was that even the right thing to get this started?

Comment: Unzip, then: File > Open > Select the Project Folder. Android Studio should offer a dialog on whether you want to open in a new window.

Comment: I'm seeing this with Android Studio 3.   The Android SDK is fine, then it's not.   The problem is NOT the Android SDK setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Please select Android SDK” is a problem with the configuration not with the project.
In some updates from android studio you can see this problem.

Solution:

```
File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Android SDK
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts in Android Studio 3.0.1 on Windows 10. Fixed by:

1. Updating the USB driver for the device (Windows: Device Manager -> SAMSUNG Android Phone -> SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface and right-click to "Update Driver" and...
2. Android Studio: Tools -> Android -> Tick "Enable ADB Integration"

I am very surprised given the dominance of Windows on the desktop and Android on mobile devices that this is such a struggle - I hope it saves someone the same hassle.

Answer (score 0):

please change your versionCode or versionName in Gradle.Build and Sync. 
after sync, you will able to run and you can change the previous version again.

Answer (score 0):

try to sync `build.gradle`

**OR**

```
Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle
```

If still not working then restart android studio...